# CheckSum8 Modulo 256 Swift

Tags: swift

I have an array of `UInt8` and I want to calculate CheckSum8 Modulo 256. 
If sum of bytes is less than 255, `checkSum` function returns correct value.

e.g

```
let bytes1 : [UInt8] = [1, 0xa1]
let validCheck = checkSum(data : bytes1) // 162 = 0xa2
let bytes : [UInt8] = [6, 0xB1, 27,0xc5,0xf5,0x9d]
let invalidCheck = checkSum(data : bytes) // 41
```

Below function returns 41 but expected checksum is 35.

```
func checkSum(data: [UInt8]) -> UInt8 {

    var sum = 0
    for i in 0..<data.count {
        sum += Int(data[i])
    }
    let retVal = sum & 0xff
    return UInt8(retVal)
}
```

Comment: The sum of your values is 0x0329, so the modulo 0xff is 0x29, which is 41.

Comment: Yes, but expexted value is 35. This web calculates Checksum8 correct for 06B127c5f59d. https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `checkSum` method is largely right. If you want, you could simplify it to:

```
func checkSum(_ values: [UInt8]) -> UInt8 {
    let result = values.reduce(0) { ($0 + UInt32($1)) & 0xff }
    return UInt8(result)
}
```

You point out a web site that reports the checksum8 for `06B127c5f59d` is `35`.

The problem is that in your array has `27`, not `0x27`. If you have hexadecimal values, you always need the `0x` prefix for each value in your array literal (or, technically, at least if the value is larger than `9`).

So, consider:

```
let values: [UInt8] = [0x06, 0xB1, 0x27, 0xc5, 0xf5, 0x9d]
let result = checkSum(values)
```

That’s `53`. If you want to see that in hexadecimal (like that site you referred to):

```
let hex = String(result, radix: 16)
```

That shows us that the checksum is `0x35` in hexadecimal.

Comment: I am creating array from bytes, how can I ensure that? Your answer is correct though.

Comment: This `0x` prefix is only an issue when you’re typing in the values in code or converting hex strings. When you’re reading in values from an array that has been populated from some external source, it’s not generally an issue. We can’t comment without seeing how you are populating this array.

Comment: Thank you Rob, You are right, I was hard coding byte values and was not converting hex 27 to Int. Using bytes directly from data evaluates correct checksum with your function.